# Sitecore 6.5 Content Delivery Problems (publishing/caching?)

Tags: caching, sitecore, publishing

We have a Sitecore 6.5 instance with separate CM and CD servers, each uses it's own core, web and master db's as well.

We are seeing issues when a new version of content is created. The CM Master and Web databases show the correct content in the  content editor. After a publish, the Web database on CD shows the correct content in the content editor.

However, the website is showing a mix of correct content and standard values.

Some things I've tried and noticed:

- Clearing cache manually as no effect.
- No publishing or cache errors in the CD or CM logs
- We've reviewed the Scalability Guide to be sure CD and CM are setup correctly
- Saving the item in the CD content editor immediately fixes the problem until a new version is created and published on CM
- Republishing vs Smart Publish has no affect
- The site is correct when viewing the CM version

I'd love to hear anyone's thoughts or questions that might steer me in the right direction.

Comment: First of all it sounds strange, that you have a separate master database for the CD environment. Secondly this sounds like an issue with event queues. Have you set that up?

Comment: Yeah, event queues were one of the first things we checked. They are setup and we can see the publish events in the CM server log.

Comment: @JensMikkelsen, regarding the master database being separate, do you think that could be related?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be related, if you can se the item correctly in the content editor. However you should check what is registered in the Event Queue table in the web database for the CD environment. If serverspecific properties aren't set correctly.

Comment: Check the time on all of the servers. They MUST be synchronized.

Comment: Thanks, @MarasMusielak. We did verify the times were synchronized. My understanding is, if they are not, cache may not be refreshed on a publish, correct?

Comment: Thanks, @JensMikkelsen. I will look into the event queue table. We do run other websites on this same Sitecore instance though that don't have this same problem. Doesn't it seem like if the Event Queue was bad, all the sites would have a problem?

Comment: Check the 'instance name' setting (in ScalabilitySetting config) on CD's server, and make sure they are all unique.

Comment: Thanks @AhmedOkour. We verified that as well - all are unique.

Comment: Maybe you should contact Sitecore support team on this, looks very strange

Answer (score 2):

We finally figured out this issue with some solid help from Sitecore support.

The pages that were "misbehaving" used the Lucene index to locate the Sitecore item and then display information from the item. In our case, the Lucene index was not being updated when the item was published.

Sitecore recommended configuring the HistoryEngine for the web databases on both CD and CM. That fixed the issue.

```
<Engines.HistoryEngine.Storage>
  <obj type="Sitecore.Data.$(database).$(database)HistoryStorage, Sitecore.Kernel">
   <param connectionStringName="$(id)" />
   <EntryLifeTime>30.00:00:00</EntryLifeTime>
  </obj>
</Engines.HistoryEngine.Storage>
<Engines.HistoryEngine.SaveDotNetCallStack>false</Engines.HistoryEngine.SaveDotNetCallStack>
```

We still have a couple things we can't explain and Sitecore couldn't either

- How was this working for other sites on the same instance in the past? What caused the issue to start now?
- Why were the pages displaying some of the items' content? Where was that coming from?

Now that I know the fix, I'll have to dig in some more to see if I can figure out these questions.

Hopefully this steers someone else in the right direction.